# Creates folder instead of file

Tags: android, file

I have tried to create file using `java.io.File` class with following set of codes:

1) with `File(String path)`:

```
String filePath = "/mnt/sdcard/myfolder/Log_201406130608.dat";
File dirMediaFile = new File(filePath); // Folder created at this point with "Log_201406130608.dat" name.
if(!dirMediaFile.exists())
{
    dirMediaFile.createNewFile();
}
```

2) with `File(File dir, String name)`

```
String dirPath = "/mnt/sdcard/myfolder";
File dirFile = new File(dirPath);
if(!dirFile.exists())
{
    dirFile.mkdir();
}
downloadingMediaFile = new File(dirFile, "Log_201406130608.dat"); // Folder created at this point with "Log_201406130608.dat" name.

if(!downloadingMediaFile.exists())
{
    downloadingMediaFile.createNewFile();
}
```

I can't understand what is the problem? please help me find out the reason of this problem.

Comment: What's the result you've got ? Is there an error (Logcat output) ? Check that you have the right to 'WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE' in your manifest.

Comment: @Guian No error in Logcat during execution of this code. Only problem is that why OS creates a directory instead of file. Is there any problem with naming convention of file??

Answer (score -1):

There is no such file name that creates a directory instead of file for you, so no, it's not a naming issue.

While hardcoding paths works on most devices, it's a bad method.

```
final String dirPath = "/mnt/sdcard/myfolder";
```

Get the path from `Envorinment` shown as below

You've probably created a directory by mistake before.

After you fixed the code, the directory is not deleted.

The following should work.

```
final File dirFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "myfolder");

if (dirFile.exists() && !dirFile.isDirectory()) {
    dirFile.delete();
}

if (!dirFile.exists()) {
    dirFile.mkdirs(); //mkdirs creates any previous directory, if not created before
}

downloadingMediaFile = new File(dirFile, "Log_201406130608.dat");

if (downloadingMediaFile.exists() && !downloadingMediaFile.isFile()) [
     // not a file, delete
    downloadingMediaFile.delete();
}

if (!downloadingMediaFile.exists())
{
    downloadingMediaFile.createNewFile();
}
```

Comment: Or just try to delete the "Log_201406130608.dat" directory before runing your code again just to be sure it wasn't there before ^^

Comment: @DevK have you tried running debugger to see at which point the directory is really created? Are you sure there isn't a similar code somewhere else that is called after and creates a directory instead?

Comment: @DoctororDrive Directory is created after this line: downloadingMediaFile = new File(dirFile, "Log_201406130608.dat");

And there are no any other code that will create this directory. And one more thing is that this line "downloadingMediaFile.delete();" not deleting the directory that was already created.

Comment: @DevK there is something wrong. `downloadingMediaFile = new File(dirFile, "Log_201406130608.dat");` does **not** perform any write operations. `File` constructor just creates the file pointer object. Also, are you sure the directory you see is named exactly "Log_201406130608.dat" (not other numbers)?